# How to use prefix tree data structure

Tags: r, trie

I have a smg file that contains different articles. Now I would like to use prefix tree data structure to establish baseline word counts for the entire corpus of documents. A sample of the file can be found below：

```
<REUTERS TOPICS="YES" LEWISSPLIT="TRAIN" CGISPLIT="TRAINING-SET" 
OLDID="5544" NEWID="1">
<DATE>26-FEB-1987 15:01:01.79</DATE>
<TOPICS><D>cocoa</D></TOPICS>
<PLACES><D>el-salvador</D><D>usa</D><D>uruguay</D></PLACES>
<PEOPLE></PEOPLE>
<ORGS></ORGS>
<EXCHANGES></EXCHANGES>
<COMPANIES></COMPANIES>
<UNKNOWN> 
&#5;&#5;&#5;C T
&#22;&#22;&#1;f0704&#31;reute
u f BC-BAHIA-COCOA-REVIEW   02-26 0105</UNKNOWN>
<TEXT>&#2;
<TITLE>BAHIA COCOA REVIEW</TITLE>
<DATELINE>    SALVADOR, Feb 26 - </DATELINE><BODY>
Some text here.
 Reuter
&#3;</BODY></TEXT>
</REUTERS>
```

Any advice on how to establish the baseline word counts?

Comment: I'm not sure trying to complete an assignment via piecemeal SO questions is the best approach. It might also help if you provided feedback consistently on previous questions before posting new ones.

Answer (score 0):

use trie data structure to load strings and retrieve suggestions faster

```
public class Trie
    {
        public struct Letter
        {
            public const string Chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
            public static implicit operator Letter(char c)
            {
                c = c.ToString().ToUpper().ToCharArray().First();

                return new Letter() { Index = Chars.IndexOf(c) };
            }
            public int Index;
            public char ToChar()
            {
                return Chars[Index];
            }
            public override string ToString()
            {
                return Chars[Index].ToString();
            }
        }

        public class Node
        {
            public string Word;
            public bool IsTerminal { get { return Word != null; } }
            public Dictionary<Letter, Node> Edges = new Dictionary<Letter, Node>();


        }

        public Node Root = new Node();

        public Trie(string[] words)
        {
            for (int w = 0; w < words.Length; w++)
            {
                var word = words[w];
                var node = Root;
                for (int len = 1; len <= word.Length; len++)
                {
                    var letter = word[len - 1];
                    Node next;
                    if (!node.Edges.TryGetValue(letter, out next))
                    {
                        next = new Node();
                        if (len == word.Length)
                        {
                            next.Word = word;
                        }
                        node.Edges.Add(letter, next);
                    }
                    node = next;
                }
            }
        }


        public List<string> GetSuggestions(string word, int max)
        {
            List<string> outPut = new List<string>();

            var node = Root;
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var l in word)
            {
                Node cNode;
                if (node.Edges.TryGetValue(l, out cNode))
                {
                    node = cNode;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (i == word.Length - 1)
                        return outPut;
                }
                i++;
            }

            GetChildWords(node, ref outPut, max);

            return outPut;
        }


        public void GetChildWords(Node n, ref List<string> outWords, int Max)
        {
            if (n.IsTerminal && outWords.Count < Max)
                outWords.Add(n.Word);

            foreach (var item in n.Edges)
            {
                GetChildWords(item.Value, ref outWords, Max);
            }
        }

    }
```